# Clear and Redraw data on Line Chart using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, linechart

I'm using line chart with Canvas. I drew with data I got. The yValue displayed data and xValue increased one step with updateInterval times like Dynamic line chart. I want to clear the data drew on line chart and redraw new data when xValue >= 200. How can I sovle this ?

Thank a lot.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function LineChart(config){
    // user defined properties
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(config.canvasId);
    this.minX = config.minX;
    this.minY = config.minY;
    this.maxX = config.maxX;
    this.maxY = config.maxY;
    this.unitsPerTickX = config.unitsPerTickX;
    this.unitsPerTickY = config.unitsPerTickY;
    // constants
    this.padding = 10;
    this.tickSize = 10;
    this.axisColor = "#555";
    this.pointRadius = 2;
    this.font = "12pt Calibri";
    /*
    * measureText does not provide a text height
    * metric, so we'll have to hardcode a text height
    * value
    */
    this.fontHeight = 12;
    // relationships
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.rangeX = this.maxX - this.minY;
    this.rangeY = this.maxY - this.minY;
    this.numXTicks = Math.round(this.rangeX / this.unitsPerTickX);
    this.numYTicks = Math.round(this.rangeY / this.unitsPerTickY);
    this.x = this.getLongestValueWidth() + this.padding * 2;
    this.y = this.padding * 2;
    this.width = this.canvas.width - this.x - this.padding * 2;
    this.height = this.canvas.height - this.y - this.padding -
    this.fontHeight;
    this.scaleX = this.width / this.rangeX;
    this.scaleY = this.height / this.rangeY;
    // draw x y axis and tick marks
    this.drawXAxis();
    this.drawYAxis();
    }
    LineChart.prototype.getLongestValueWidth = function(){
    this.context.font = this.font;
    var longestValueWidth = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n <= this.numYTicks; n++) {
    var value = this.maxY - (n * this.unitsPerTickY);
    longestValueWidth = Math.max(longestValueWidth, this.
    context.measureText(value).width);
    }
    return longestValueWidth;
    };
    LineChart.prototype.drawXAxis = function(){
    var context = this.context;
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.x, this.y + this.height);
    context.lineTo(this.x + this.width, this.y + this.height);
    context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.stroke();
    // draw tick marks
    for (var n = 0; n < this.numXTicks; n++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo((n + 1) * this.width / this.numXTicks +
    this.x, this.y + this.height);
    context.lineTo((n + 1) * this.width / this.numXTicks +
    this.x, this.y + this.height - this.tickSize);
    context.stroke();
    }
    // draw labels
    context.font = this.font;
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";
    for (var n = 0; n < this.numXTicks; n++) {
    var label = Math.round((n + 1) * this.maxX / this.
    numXTicks);
    context.save();
    context.translate((n + 1) * this.width / this.numXTicks +
    this.x, this.y + this.height + this.padding);
    context.fillText(label, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
    }
    context.restore();
    };
    LineChart.prototype.drawYAxis = function(){
    var context = this.context;
    context.save();
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    context.lineTo(this.x, this.y + this.height);
    context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
    // draw tick marks
    for (var n = 0; n < this.numYTicks; n++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.x, n * this.height / this.numYTicks +
    this.y);
    context.lineTo(this.x + this.tickSize, n * this.height /
    this.numYTicks + this.y);
    context.stroke();
        }
    // draw values
    context.font = this.font;
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.textAlign = "right";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";
    for (var n = 0; n < this.numYTicks; n++) {
    var value = Math.round(this.maxY - n * this.maxY / this.numYTicks);
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x - this.padding, n * this.height /
    this.numYTicks + this.y);
    context.fillText(value, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
    }
    context.restore();
    };
    LineChart.prototype.drawLine = function(data, color, width){
    var context = this.context;
    context.save();
    this.transformContext();
    context.lineWidth = width;
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(data[0].x * this.scaleX, data[0].y * this.
    scaleY);
    for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
    var point = data[n];
    // draw segment
    context.lineTo(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.
    scaleY);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.scaleY,
    this.pointRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    // position for next segment
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.scaleY);
    }
    context.restore();
    };
    LineChart.prototype.transformContext = function(){
    var context = this.context;
    // move context to center of canvas
    this.context.translate(this.x, this.y + this.height);
    // invert the y scale so that that increments
    // as you move upwards
    context.scale(1, -1);
    };
    window.onload = function(){
    var myLineChart = new LineChart({
    canvasId: "myCanvas",
    minX: 0,
    minY: 0,
    maxX: 200,
    maxY: 260,
    unitsPerTickX: 20,
    unitsPerTickY: 50
    });
    var dps = [];
    var xVal = dps.length + 1;
    var yVal ;
    var updateInterval = 100;
    function updatedata(){
    yVal = xVal;
    dps.push({x: xVal,y: yVal});
    xVal++;
    myLineChart.drawLine(dps, "blue", 3);       
    };
    setInterval(function(){updatedata()}, updateInterval); 
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To re-animate the same line just clear `dps` and reset `xVal`**

In your `updatedata` function, test if `xVal>200`. If yes:

- clear the canvas
- redraw the X & Y axes
- reset the `dps` array to zero length
- reset `xVal` to dps.length+1

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
function LineChart(config){
  // user defined properties
  this.canvas = document.getElementById(config.canvasId);
  this.minX = config.minX;
  this.minY = config.minY;
  this.maxX = config.maxX;
  this.maxY = config.maxY;
  this.unitsPerTickX = config.unitsPerTickX;
  this.unitsPerTickY = config.unitsPerTickY;
  // constants
  this.padding = 10;
  this.tickSize = 10;
  this.axisColor = "#555";
  this.pointRadius = 2;
  this.font = "12pt Calibri";
  /*
        * measureText does not provide a text height
        * metric, so we'll have to hardcode a text height
        * value
        */
  this.fontHeight = 12;
  // relationships
  this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.rangeX = this.maxX - this.minY;
  this.rangeY = this.maxY - this.minY;
  this.numXTicks = Math.round(this.rangeX / this.unitsPerTickX);
  this.numYTicks = Math.round(this.rangeY / this.unitsPerTickY);
  this.x = this.getLongestValueWidth() + this.padding * 2;
  this.y = this.padding * 2;
  this.width = this.canvas.width - this.x - this.padding * 2;
  this.height = this.canvas.height - this.y - this.padding -
    this.fontHeight;
  this.scaleX = this.width / this.rangeX;
  this.scaleY = this.height / this.rangeY;
  // draw x y axis and tick marks
  this.drawXAxis();
  this.drawYAxis();
}
LineChart.prototype.getLongestValueWidth = function(){
  this.context.font = this.font;
  var longestValueWidth = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n <= this.numYTicks; n++) {
    var value = this.maxY - (n * this.unitsPerTickY);
    longestValueWidth = Math.max(longestValueWidth, this.
                                 context.measureText(value).width);
  }
  return longestValueWidth;
};
//
LineChart.prototype.drawXAxis = function(){
  var context = this.context;
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(this.x, this.y + this.height);
  context.lineTo(this.x + this.width, this.y + this.height);
  context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  // draw tick marks
  for (var n = 0; n < this.numXTicks; n++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo((n + 1) * this.width / this.numXTicks +
                   this.x, this.y + this.height);
    context.lineTo((n + 1) * this.width / this.numXTicks +
                   this.x, this.y + this.height - this.tickSize);
    context.stroke();
  }
  // draw labels
  context.font = this.font;
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  for (var n = 0; n < this.numXTicks; n++) {
    var label = Math.round((n + 1) * this.maxX / this.
                           numXTicks);
    context.save();
    context.translate((n + 1) * this.width / this.numXTicks +
                      this.x, this.y + this.height + this.padding);
    context.fillText(label, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
  }
  context.restore();
};
//
LineChart.prototype.drawYAxis = function(){
  var context = this.context;
  context.save();
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
  context.lineTo(this.x, this.y + this.height);
  context.strokeStyle = this.axisColor;
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
  // draw tick marks
  for (var n = 0; n < this.numYTicks; n++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.x, n * this.height / this.numYTicks +
                   this.y);
    context.lineTo(this.x + this.tickSize, n * this.height /
                   this.numYTicks + this.y);
    context.stroke();
  }
  // draw values
  context.font = this.font;
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.textAlign = "right";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  for (var n = 0; n < this.numYTicks; n++) {
    var value = Math.round(this.maxY - n * this.maxY / this.numYTicks);
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x - this.padding, n * this.height /
                      this.numYTicks + this.y);
    context.fillText(value, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
  }
  context.restore();
};
//
LineChart.prototype.drawLine = function(data, color, width){
  var context = this.context;
  context.save();
  this.transformContext();
  context.lineWidth = width;
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(data[0].x * this.scaleX, data[0].y * this.
                 scaleY);
  for (var n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
    var point = data[n];
    // draw segment
    context.lineTo(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.
                   scaleY);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.scaleY,
                this.pointRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    // position for next segment
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(point.x * this.scaleX, point.y * this.scaleY);
  }
  context.restore();
};
//
LineChart.prototype.transformContext = function(){
  var context = this.context;
  // move context to center of canvas
  this.context.translate(this.x, this.y + this.height);
  // invert the y scale so that that increments
  // as you move upwards
  context.scale(1, -1);
};
//
//
window.onload = function(){
  var myLineChart = new LineChart({
    canvasId: "myCanvas",
    minX: 0,
    minY: 0,
    maxX: 200,
    maxY: 260,
    unitsPerTickX: 20,
    unitsPerTickY: 50
  });
  //
  var dps = [];
  var xVal = dps.length + 1;
  var yVal ;
  var updateInterval = 100;
  var color='blue';
  function updatedata(){
    if(xVal>200){
      myLineChart.context.clearRect(0,0,myLineChart.canvas.width,myLineChart.canvas.height);
      myLineChart.drawXAxis();
      myLineChart.drawYAxis();
      dps.length=0;
      xVal=dps.length+1;
      color=(color=='blue')?'red':'blue';
    }
    //
    yVal = xVal;
    dps.push({x: xVal,y: yVal});
    xVal++;
    myLineChart.drawLine(dps, color, 3);       

  };
  setInterval(function(){updatedata()}, updateInterval); 
};
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```